# How can I get only the first label relationship on laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eager-loading, laravel-relations

I have `SaleInvoice` model,
Sale invoice belongs to `User` model and `User` model belongs to another model called `Client`.
On the `User` model I am using eager loading to load the `Client`

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{

    /**
     * The relations to eager load on every query.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $with = ['client'];
}
```

Problem is, when I eager loads `User` with `SaleInvoice` model, it also loads the `Client`

```
class SaleInvoice extends Model
{

    /**
     * The relations to eager load on every query.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $with = ['user'];
}
```

** Is there any way to only load the `User` with `SaleInvoice`?
Note: It is also important to load `Client` with `User`

Comment: I would suggest removing the `$with` properties from your models and just be explicit with your queries e.g. `SaleInvoice::with('user')->get();`. The `$with` should only really be used if you know for certain that you're always going to want to load a particular relationship. If there are times when you don't want this to happen (or you end up with a circular dependency), then it shouldn't be used.

Comment: Is there any way to dynamically add accessors on paginated date collection?

Comment: You can use `tap`.